# How to position an image in a CSS designed Bar graph

Tags: html, css

I am creating a bar graph and i want to be able to position the image inside each bar without altering the bars size. I have found a way to implement this through text but i can not do the same with an image. Is this possible? Or would it be more flexible if i put the image to the left of the bar instead like a traditional bar graph?.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>SF6</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <section id="tall">
            <article class="tall">
                
                <div>
                <p>Sages <img src ="./badge/some_stuff_for_richard5.png" height="50" ><span></span><span class="tall"></span></p>
            </div>
            <article class="tall">
                <div>
                <p>prophet<span></span><span class="tall"></span></p>
            </div>
            <article class="tall">
                <div>
                <p>renegade<span></span><span class="tall"></span></p>
            </div>
        </article>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>

html{
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
body{
    background-color: #1a1a2e ;
}
html,
body,
main{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
main{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center ;
    align-items: center;
}

section{
    background: #1a1a2e
}
section article.tall{
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
}
section article.tall p {
    color:#ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    position:relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;


}
section article.tall p img{
    color:#ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    position:relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;

}
section article.tall div span:nth-child(1){
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin:auto;
    background: #0f3460;
    z-index: -2;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
section article.tall div span:nth-child(2){
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin:auto;
    background: rgb(94,227,255);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(94,227,255,1) 0%, rgba(11,113,230,1) 100%);
    z-index: -1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Flex and get what you want with some changes, but I didn't understand what you wanted, so I wrote what I got from your question.

```
 <main>
    <section id="tall">
        <article class="tall">
            <div>
                <p>Sages <img src ="./badge/some_stuff_for_richard5.png" style="margin-left: 10px;"><span></span><span class="tall"></span></p>
            </div>
        <article class="tall">
            <div>
                <p><img src ="./badge/some_stuff_for_richard5.png" style="margin-right: 10px;">prophet<span></span><span class="tall"></span></p>
            </div>
        <article class="tall">
            <div>
                <p>renegade<img src ="./badge/some_stuff_for_richard5.png" style="margin-left: 10px;"><span></span><span class="tall"></span></p>
            </div>
    </article>
    </section>
</main>
```

```
html{
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
body{
    background-color: #1a1a2e ;
}
html,
body,
main{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
main{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center ;
    align-items: center;
}

section{
    background: #1a1a2e
}
section article.tall{
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
}
section article.tall p {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    position:relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 38px;
}
section article.tall p img{
    display: block;
    color:#ffffff;
    position:relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 30px;
}

section article.tall div span:nth-child(1){
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin:auto;
    background: #0f3460;
    z-index: -2;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
section article.tall div span:nth-child(2){
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin:auto;
    background: rgb(94,227,255);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(94,227,255,1) 0%, rgba(11,113,230,1) 100%);
    z-index: -1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[About flex and align-items...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

[image: output]

Comment: Yeah this was what i was looking for my issue was that anytime i inserted an img into the  bar it would alter the bar size and make it look different than the rest when i just wanted the image to take up more space in the bar without making it larger